# unable to install mysql 5.5 using brew or dmg

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I am unable to install mysql5.5 using brew or dmg..
here is the output of brew install mysql55

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall homebrew/versions/mysql55`
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Conflicts with mysql, mariadb, percona-server, mysql-cluster, etc.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/mysql55/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/mysql55/include
```

To reload homebrew/versions/mysql55 after an upgrade:
  launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql55.plist
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql55.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mysql.server start

when i do mysql.server start it says

$ ./mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql55/bhaware.nikhil.pid).

please help me...